# TwiML <Stream> won't stream constantly

Tags: flask, twilio, twilio-twiml

I have Twilio API with flask and python as a development platform, i'm following.

TwiML [TwiML `<Stream>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/stream)

Now i have the server endpoint to receive the message in JSON and at the end i can parse the bytes out of it.
But just like the API says it gets connected and gets disconnected if it does not have a proceeding instruction in our case TwiML Verb. The most obvious verb seems to be a `<Dial>` verb.

here is the referrence https://stackoverflow.com/a/36315684/6215280

Now our main goal is to just receive bytes from the caller and send him back the processed data. But here since the call gets disconnected i am limited to call to other person to keep the TwiML Bin running.

I have looked for API and haven't found any way to keep the `<Stream>` in loop.
Is there any way without `<Dial>` to person B i can receive and send bytes.

Any help would be appreciated @philnash

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [Twilio Media Streams github repo](https://github.com/twilio/media-streams), a TwiML Pause verb is used for that purpose, if you don't want to Dial or Conference.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
  <Start>
    <Stream url="wss://<ngrok url>/"></Stream>
  </Start>
  <Pause length="40"/>
</Response>
```

Comment: After doing this im left with the issue that i;m receiving same data in bytes i.e a -2 value. Not being able to get audio data accurately through stream.

Comment: i have marked this is as the answer thanks! can you please take a look here aswel? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58803813/how-to-receive-and-send-back-bytes-audio-data-to-twilio