# How to receive and send back bytes audio data to Twilio?

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

I have been working on a Twilio project and i have set everything up using this guide: [Stream TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/consume-real-time-media-stream-using-websockets-python-and-flask?code-sample=code-decode-the-json-message-5&code-language=Python&code-sdk-version=default)

i have already resolved a common issue with the help of Alan here [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58800337/6215280)

I'm unable to send back the processed bytes I'm using.

```
ws.send(bytes)
ws.receive()
```

These two methods i assume are required to send and receive back and forth data using the web socket.
But im receving a constant data stream from twilio.

That's:
 `b'\xfe\xfe\xfe\xfe\xfe\xfe\xfe\xfe\xfe\xfe\xfe\xfe\xfe\xfe\xfe\xfe\xfe\xfe\xfe\xfe\xfe\xfe\xfe\xfe\xfe\xfe\xfe\xfe\xfe\xfe\xfe\xfe\xfe\xfe\xfe\xfe\xfe\xf`

Which does not makes any sense. The guide officially says you can get bytes from real time call and then send them. So let's say i receive bytes and process them using my custom logic maybe storing it somewhere. My processing outputs the same PCM/16Bit Mono audio data in bytes. Which i think twilio is also send me raw bytes as it says in the documentation that it gives out raw bytes (which i assume are without any kind of encoding). So all i want here is to receive audio data sent from the caller to twilio to receive and send bytes to an endpoint which i have setup ed earlier in flask to handle and then i can process it a little bit and return PCM bytes to it which can be played back at the caller side.

All i want is to caller send his voice and gets processed and receives back maybe our voices added to it as well. It wont matter how the byte is treated here my concept is to add some audio data to it and send back.

But since  verb is new so there's no where i can find how to properly handle the bytes and send them back.

It would be nice if someone can point me what twilio expects in the web socket return as a audio data that it can be played on the caller side. And what i should be expecting from twilio. But since in the documentation it says that payload sends out raw bytes so i assume its a plain PCM data in bytes.

Please let me know so i can receive bytes from twilio and send them back which can be played at the caller side and caller's voice can be heard from here.I have players and clients setup ed as well to play the byte data but since the data is plain or recursive i cannot play it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

As far as I know right now Media Streams only supports streaming the data to your server one way. You cannot stream media back to Twilio via the websocket connection.

If you were able to save the bytes you want to send back as an audio file, you can play it back to the call by [redirecting the call](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call-resource#update-a-call-resource) to some TwiML that [`<Play>`s the audio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/play) to the call.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Okay that's the second part of the story, im able to save the bytes to mp3 or wav that's not an issue but the thing is that im receiving constant dummy bytes that i mentioned in my comment. The documentation is not good enough to shed light on proper constant byte retrieval from calls. And i assume you have not read on twilio official it says: https://www.twilio.com/media-streams

"Using Media Streams, you can pass voice data to a third-party to perform a task and route that voice data back into Twilio."

Comment: So two things that are confusing me 1. You are saying i cannt send back data directly through the web socket but twilio says we can?
2. The data that's being recvied using the documentation on <Stream> verb is constant and has no audio able data that can be played. Even though i can receive it and can apply processing to it, it's not valuable data as its giving me constant dummy byte data.