# Stream audio back to Twilio via websocket connection

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

I'm trying out Twillio's **Programmable Voice** feature and have implemented basic audio stream processing by referring to [this doc](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/consume-real-time-media-stream-using-websockets-python-and-flask). I'm planning to stream audio back to Twillio using the same websocket and want Twillio to play that audio to the caller

Is there any way to achieve this?

This is how my TwiML bins app xml configuration looks like

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Start>
        <Stream url="wss://XXXXXXX.in.ngrok.io/media" />
    </Start>
     <Dial>+91**********</Dial>
</Response>
```

I referred to [Twillio Bi-directional Media-Streams](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/stream#bi-directional-media-streams), but it doesn't specify in what format and with what structure I need to send audio bytes back to twillio

Also I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58803813/how-to-receive-and-send-back-bytes-audio-data-to-twilio) question where in answer he says sending back audio stream back to twillio websocket is not possible.

Can I get some help here please, to understand how can I achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very late to answer, but it's possible. Refer to this section: https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/stream#websocket-messages-to-twilio

Essentially, you're using the websocket to send back data across the connection. You should send back JSON in text/bytes mode.

Here's an example JSON that was provided in the docs:

```
{
  "event": "media",
  "streamSid": "MZ18ad3ab5a668481ce02b83e7395059f0",
  "media": {
    "payload": "a3242sadfasfa423242... (a base64 encoded string of 8000/mulaw)"
  }
}
```

I'm personally using Amazon Polly for TTS. Here is an example of how to use Polly:

```py
class Manager:
    def __init__(self):
        self._exit_stack = AsyncExitStack()
        self._s3_client = None

    async def __aenter__(self):
        session = AioSession()
        self._s3_client = await self._exit_stack.enter_async_context(
            session.create_client("s3")
        )

    async def __aexit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        await self._exit_stack.__aexit__(exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb)


async def create_client(service: str, session: AioSession, exit_stack: AsyncExitStack):
    client = await exit_stack.enter_async_context(session.create_client(service))
    return client


WORD = "<speak>"


async def synthesize_speech(text: str, voice_id: str = "Matthew"):
    session = AioSession()

    async with AsyncExitStack() as exit_stack:
        polly = await create_client("polly", session, exit_stack)
        try:
            response = await polly.synthesize_speech(
                Text=text,
                TextType="ssml" if WORD in text else "text",
                OutputFormat="pcm",
                VoiceId=voice_id,
                SampleRate="8000",
            )
        except (BotoCoreError, ClientError) as error:
            logger.error(error)
            raise HTTPException(500, "Failed to synthesize speech")
        else:
            mulaw_audio = await response["AudioStream"].read()
            audio = audioop.lin2ulaw(mulaw_audio, 2)
            base64_audio = base64.b64encode(audio).decode("utf-8")
            return base64_audio
```

And then here's the example of how to send back websocket data in FastAPI:

```py
from fastapi import WebSocketDisconnect

@app.websocket("/stream")
async def websocket(ws: WebSocket):
    await ws.accept()
    stream_sid = None
    try:
        while True:
            packet = await ws.receive_json()
            if packet["event"] == "start":
                # Save the stream SID for later use
                # I would go as far as saving most of the start message
                stream_sid = packet["streamSid"]
                continue

            # Send audio back:
            await ws.send_json(
                {
                  "event": "media",
                  "streamSid": stream_sid,
                  "media": {
                    "payload": await synthesize_speech("Hello world!")
                  }
                }
            )
            # If you want to send multiple audio messages
            # You should send a mark message. You'll receive
            # a mark event back where you can send the next audio

    except WebSocketDisconnect:
        pass
```

I recommend after sending the media message that you send a mark message. This allows you to know when your audio is done playing. In that case, you can batch your audio requests to Amazon Polly and send them sequentially.

Comment: hey acw, I have a related question.  It looks like you're waiting for the full syntehsize_speech function to return.  What if you wanted to stream audio chunks to twilio? Is that possible or would it end up choppy?

Comment: I developed a method that synthesized speech in portions by splitting by punctuation. I would then send to Polly all these chunks, with the first parts of what I want to say be shorter than chunks to be said later. This way, the first chunk is said as soon as possible. There is a lot of nuance to conversational AI such as responding ASAP and stop talking when someone else is talking, but if you keep in mind the ease of using asyncio (i.e. asyncio.create_task ;), things will start becoming easy in terms of time. I would take advantage of the tags they provide like <break> as well

Comment: How would this work in flask? I've been trying to do something with flask_sock package but i've been getting async subroutine errors... wonder if fastapi abstracts that

Comment: if flask supports asyncio, i doubt it's a flask problem. Not sure what might be "abstracted" from your POV

Comment: @acw: shouldn't the `await websocket.send_json` be `await ws.send_json`?