# Cann't send back data using websocket for Twilio call

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

I've been working on Twilio project and have set up everything like in this tutorial: [link](https://medium.com/@atgorvi/twilio-voice-chat-assistant-using-azure-speech-recognition-and-python-efaf6319b583).

I receive bytes using "ws.receive()", but I have trouble on the stage of sending bytes of voice back.

For this I used this function:

```
ws.send(bytes)
```

Also I saw the post on StackOverflow, that says "Media Streams only supports streaming the data to your server one way. You cannot stream media back to Twilio via the websocket connection."([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58803813/how-to-receive-and-send-back-bytes-audio-data-to-twilio)). But this post was 4 years before the project, I mentioned earlier was posted on "medium.com".

I'm interested is it actually possible to send data back using "ws.send()", because I didn't found better explanation why this might not work. If not so, please let me know how can I do this instead.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio Support Engineer here. It's possible to send data back if the stream is setup as a bi-directional media stream using the  noun. For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
   <Connect>
       <Stream url="wss://mystream.ngrok.io/audiostream" />
   </Connect>
</Response>
```

The only support events are [Media Message](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/stream#message-media-to-twilio) and [Mark Message](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/stream#message-mark-to-twilio). When sending media, you need to ensure that you are sending audio that is encoded in mulaw and that does not contain any header information.